# How to display records based on hasmany relationship using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How to display all users based on subscriptions status,like display all premium users first in the list, then gold, silver, free users etc ?

```
User::with('subscriptions')->get(); // List of all users with subscriptions.

// Users Model
public function subscriptions() 
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Subscription');
}

// View

@foreach($users as $user)
   {{ $user->name }}

@endoreach
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you have your tables set up, but this should work for you (using a field called `level` within subscriptions):

```
User::with(['subscriptions' => function($query){
    $query->orderBy('subscriptions.level');
}])->get();
```

This should order according to the 'level' of the subscription.  Then, in your blade view (assuming some kind of table or something), you can call the user name and then the level of subscription based on the relationship:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
 <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
 <td>
      @foreach($user->subscriptions as $sub)
        {{ $sub->level}}
        {{$loop->last? "":" | "}}
      @endforeach
 </td>
@endforeach
```

This is one way to provide for multiple subscriptions - using a pipe in between each within the table cell for Subscription level

Comment: Thank you.this should work, but this will repeat the user if have multiple subscriptions?

Comment: Yes, it can.  It gets a little more complex though.  You would possibly wish to add a second loop in your blade inside the existing foreach (`foreach@user->subsciptions as $sub`) or similar.  OR, you can query on the reverse (query against **Subscriptions** with `user`) and then loop on the subscriptions.  But that's perhaps a different question - this should work for your original question :)  I will edit to show the extra foreach loop: